# Curvature universal abelian variety

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, curvature

I am reading N.Mok's paper "Aspects of Kähler Geometry on Arithmetic varieties", I am especially interested in the computation of the curvature for the space $\mathcal{H}_g \times \mathbb{C}^g$, where $ \mathcal{H}_g$ denotes Siegel's upper half space of $g\times g$ symmetric complex matrices of positive definite imaginary part.

One can put a 1-parameter family of Kähler metrics on $\mathcal{H}_g \times \mathbb{C}^g$ defied by
$$
\nu_t = i \partial \bar{\partial} \left( 2t^2 (\mathrm{Im}w)^t(\mathrm{Im}z)^{-1}(\mathrm{Im}w) +\log\det(\mathrm{Im}z)^{-1} \right)
$$
where $(z,w)$ are local holomorphic coordinates in $\mathcal{H}_g\times \mathbb{C}^g$.
Using the projection map $\mathcal{H}_g\times \mathbb{C}^g\to \mathcal{H}_g$ one can define a splitting of the tangent bundle to $\mathcal{H}_g\times \mathbb{C}^g$ into horizontal plus vertical tangent bundles, which is used to define the metrics $\nu_t$.

Denoting $T^t$ the curvature tensor of $\mathcal{H}_g\times \mathbb{C}^g$ one can prove that the only non-zero terms are

- $T^t_{h, \bar{h}, h, \bar{h}}$
- $ T^t_{h, \bar{h}, v,\bar{v}}$
- $T^t_{v, \bar{v}, v, \bar{v}}$

where $h$ and $v$ represent respectively horizontal and vertical tangent vectors and two occurrences of the same symbol may represent different vectors.

Without any further explanation it is claimed on p.378 that
$$
T^t_{v, \bar{v},v,\bar{v}} = t^4 \left| h(v,v)\right|^2
$$
where $h$ is the (normalized) hermitian metric on the vertical tangent bundle induced by $\nu_t$

Any idea why this is true?

Comment: I wouldn't expect further explanation since this paper is a survey. Did you look at the actual paper (by Mok-To) where this is done? It is here: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002211084

Comment: @YangMills yes, I had a look at that paper, however I couldn't find any mention of this fact.